# Браузер картинок

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, macos

Хочу для себя написать простой брузер картинок. Можно ли использовать NSCollectionView? И если мне нужно будет из коллекции картинок выбрать любую просмотреть ее в увеличенном (в пределах приложения) варианте, что тогда использовать? Вот в последнем моменте немного запутался. Т.е. позволяет ли NSCollectionView просмотреть один из его компонентов массива в нем же отдельно?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, вот хороший вариант - [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Чтобы отдельно посмотреть элемент, надо открывать его в другом `UIViewController`-е по нажатию на элемент, выглядит это примерно так

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoViewController *photoViewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
    photoViewController.photo = [myPhotoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это под iOS, а мне нужно под какао. Там немножко по другому.

Comment: Хотя можно попробовать, при клике на картинку, растягивать итем (состоящий из NSView) на всю ширину-высоту компонента NSCollectionView (это как один из вариантов).

Comment: Или создать два NSView, и в один из них поместить NSCollectionView. А потом переключаться с анимацией.